# Embedding of manifolds of constant negative curvature

Tags: manifolds, curvature, compact-manifolds

Consider the manifold of constant negative curvature $G=SL(2, R)/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is such that $G$ is compact (I have no special constraint on $\Gamma$).  I know that by the Whitney embedding theorem it can embedded in $R^m$ for some $m$.  However, I would like to know an **actual** explicit embedding.  Any idea, pointers?

In order to clarify my request, maybe it is worth to explain why I need the embedding. I would like to numerically solve some differential equations on G (let me skip lots of details).  In order to do that, you could  represent in your code an element  of $G$ like a triple of floating point numbers, but in this case you would need at each step to "normalize" your triple by doing a kind of "reduction modulo $\Gamma$."  This reduction introduces a "discontinuity" that causes several numerical issues. Therefore,  I would like to "represent" $G$ in my code in a smooth way and an embedding in $R^m$ looks like a nice solution.

Comment: Just a note: $SL(2,R)/\Gamma$ is not a negatively curved manifold.